# Using dynamodb document client on step function workflow

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions, aws-serverless

Am trying to get results for a `getItem` action as "normal" json instead of the DynamoDB json format on my step function workflow.

If i use:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:getItem"
```

On my ASL file i get the DynamoDB json format, for example:

```
{
 "entity_id": {
  "S": "d0e96ad0-4f83-4aa7-bcaf-2cf02c6216cb"
 }
}
```

And i need:

```
{
 "entity_id": "d0e96ad0-4f83-4aa7-bcaf-2cf02c6216cb"
}
```

I could create lambdas to interact with dynamo and use de sdk documentClient but it will be really convenient to be able to do that directly with the ASL template.

So far i tried something like:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:dynamodb:documentClient:getItem"
```

But is not valid for the template. Also did a bit of research into intrinsic functions with no success, i could also do some mapping and use `ResultSelector` but at that point i guess is better to use a lambda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stepfunctions uses Java SDK V2 to interact with DynamoDB and unfortunately can only return DynamoDB JSON. You would need to use a utility function on the client side to parse the DDB JSON or as you mentioned use a document client in Lambda.

Comment: Do you have such an intrinsic function at hand? :D Would help a lot

Comment: In Java V2 I'm not sure, but here is js and boto3: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/exploring-amazon-dynamodb-sdk-clients/

Comment: I mean an intrinsic function within Step Functions. This is independent of the SDK and language, right?