# How can I use DynamoGetItem in a step function to get a normal object?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to get an item from dynamo but it comes back as

```json
{
    "Item": {
        "sk": {
            "S": "signup"
        },
        "pk": {
            "S": "user-123"
        },
        "email": {
            "S": "foo@bar.com"
        }
    },
    // header data, etc....

}
```

I'm trying

```js
    // id-lookup table
    const table = Table.fromTableName(this, 'redacted', 'redacted');
    const getItem = new DynamoGetItem(this, 'GetItemStep', {
      table,
      key: {
        pk: DynamoAttributeValue.fromString(JsonPath.stringAt('$.body.req.id')),
        sk: DynamoAttributeValue.fromString('signup'),
      },
      resultSelector: {
        body: {
          'res.$': '$.Item',
        },
      },
      // outputPath: '$.Item',
    });
```

But I can't get rid of the obnoxious `{S: any}` thing its doing. I've done hours of research in JSONPath and I'm not convinced its at all possible to get an object, select a child, and maintain the keys.

I know about lambas, but I'm specifically looking for a stepFunction task or filter or similar.

Comment: Is it a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75110109/using-dynamodb-document-client-on-step-function-workflow?

Comment: @TofigHasanov Not sure. I know about lambdas but I'm specifically looking for a stepFunction way of doing things. like using JSONPath, intrinsic functions, or the Pass stepFunctionTask. I've researched a lot but nothing fits that bill.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to achieve this in Step Functions without using Lambda. If you know the exact schema, then you can probably build a new object from the response field by field, but at that point I would seriously consider using Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

StepFunction itself cannot retrieve the data in native JSON format as it uses the low level client and thats how it works. But when you retrieve the item, you can easily convert it with the unmarshall function:

```
const { marshall, unmarshall } = require("@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb");

let myItem = unmarshall(getFromSf())
```

Comment: That is true but it could also be achieved with an intrinsic function right?

Comment: Yes you're correct

Comment: But there is no intrinsic function for that, right? Or is there?